# Font with similar punctuation as FF DIN

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

I just discovered the "DIN" font-family and I absolutely love these geometric, angled-off commas and quotation marks. [See for yourself.](https://www.fonts.com/de/font/fontfont/ff-din)

Is there any other font-family that has this kind of geometric punctuation? (Preferably a free font-family)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite a wonky font unless you use all-caps, but [Railway](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/railway) does this. That said, FF DIN is an absolutely wonderful font, with considerable attention to detail, so if you want the best you're not going to do better. I've run into alternative DIN revivals that have weird features and limitations like a % sign that doesn't go well with the rest of the font.

There's also a DIN font on macOS although it's deprecated. You can select it in apps like Word which roll their own font loading code (it's DIN Alternate Bold), copy it into other apps and it'll work.